# Error: "Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, async-await, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a test scenario, and it throws the error: "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, make sure "done()" is called; if it returns a Promise, check if it resolves. "

I can not solve this, Below my code.

Please help me

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
const { describe, it, beforeEach, afterEach } = require('mocha');
const LoginPage = require('../pages/PageLogin');


//chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());
let driver =  new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

describe('Login', () =>  {


 beforeEach(async function () {
 driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
 loginPage = new LoginPage(driver); await loginPage.visit();

 });
 

 afterEach(async function () {
   await driver.quit();
 });


 // Define the test case
 it('should handle errors in asynchronous operation', async function(){
  await loginPage.setUsername('SRV_GHQ_ITSEngQA@AAAAAAAAA');
  await loginPage.setPassword(']7}fk3tbuRP~G3^cf?VChd5Qe3y{-]'); 
  await loginPage.clickLoginButton();
 
}).done();
})
```